# Convert Oracle cursor to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, oracle10g

How can I convert following `Oracle` line to `MYSQL`?

```
cur_var                 rout_acc_cursor%ROWTYPE;
```

type of rout_acc_cursor is CURSOR

these cur_var and rout_acc_cursor is used as follows

```
 OPEN rout_acc_cursor;
```

FETCH rout_acc_cursor

```
INTO cur_var;
```

WHILE rout_acc_cursor%FOUND

LOOP
      routing_ac := cur_var.routing_ac;

```
  --  sharicomplient := cur_var.u06_sharia_complient;

  sexchange := cur_var.u06_exchange;

  comm_cat := cur_var.u06_commision_type;

  comm_group_id := cur_var.u06_commision_group_id;

  parms :=


        parms
     || '!'
     || cur_var.u06_exchange
     || ','
     || cur_var.u06_routing_ac_type
     || ','
     || NVL (routing_ac, '*')
     || ',';
```

Comment: Not by itself. This type of declaration is for Oracle PL/SQL. What do you intend to do? Please list more sample code.

Comment: @GuidoLeenders I added more code to the question.

Comment: I think that line creates a cur_var cursor with the type of rout_acc_cursor's row type. Am I correct?

Comment: You can't. For mysql, declare one variable for each column, then lust the variables into which you fetch the riw's colons via a FETCH ... INTO commend.

Comment: Yes, correct. Or find a PL/SQL alike interpreter to runs on MySQL as backend storage.